# openvpn to display user name in status log (w/o authentication)

Tags: openvpn

I did some research and it seems it requires some more time while the problem (seemingly) simple, requiring probably some simple exact steps to follow.

Situation: openvpn server is authenticating using the certificates. I will have several clients connecting using same certificate (option enabled).

Problem: when it happens, I just see a number of similar logged lines in the status log, not being able to identify who is who.

Question: I can add "option username" to the client configuration - what steps should I do in the server and in the client to have the client indicated user name to display in the "user id" field in the status log so that I can differentiate connections?

That seems not to be that simple because, as I learnt for user name to become "effective" openvpn server must authenticate against it - this means server must have list of users and passwords (may I have empty password?), I may not be able to just set arbitrary user name. And this username/password must go in addition to certificate authentication, not instead...

Edit:

client side - `auth-user-pass <filename>` with `<filename>` containing user name on first line and password on second line

server side - `auth-user-pass-verify <script> <options>` where script must return 0 for succeeded authentication

Edit:

openvpn keeps saying in logs

```
daemon.err openvpn(login)[8992]: Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in /etc/openvpn/login.conf:1: mylogin (2.5.3)
```

where login.conf only contains two lines

```
mylogin
mypassword
```

thus for some reason advice found on the internet does not work :(

Edit:

WTF login file should not be named .conf because openvpn thinks it is its config file! Name whatever (.txt) but not .conf!

**Solution:**

Server side:

1. add to the server configuration

```
auth-user-pass-verify /etc/openvpn/verify.sh via-file
username-as-common-name
script-security 2
```

2. create `/etc/openvpn/verify.sh` on the server with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

exit 0
```

3. give `/etc/openvpn/verify.sh` permissions 0777

Client side:

4. add `--auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/login.txt` into the command line for starting openvpn
5. create `/etc/openvpn/login.txt` and put the following contents into there

```
username123
password456
```

6. give permissions for `/etc/openvpn/login.txt` for openvpn to be able to access.

and at the end you will see in status file on the server

```
CLIENT_LIST,username123,<ip:port>,<ip>,,...,...,<date>,<unixtime>,username123,0,0
```

Comment: Configuring OpenVPN to use one cert among multiple people is bad practice in general - it takes all of two minutes to generate individual certs for each user, then combine certs and key into a `.p12` cert for distribution. If a lot of certs need to be generated for a lot of users, copy paste into a simple script. Correct way of configuring an OpenVPN server would prevent the issue being experienced altogether

Comment: Thanks, but it is not a subject of question. It is clear you are correct, but situation as in the question.

Comment: Please refer to the OpenVPN man page and docs - it's why it has to be manually specified in a config. Allowing clients to share a single cert allows for easy compromising of the VPN, and if the key isn't passphrase encrypted, it's massively insecure _(certs are easy to copy & don't require elevated permissions to do so, smartphones store certs in user land storage, not system, so instead of worrying about any one unique cert being compromised, an attacker has a single point of entry, and if the cert's private key isn't encrypted, the VPN is definitely not secure)_. This info is easily found.